# Is there a formula for finding the number of nonisomorphic simple graphs that have n nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

As my subject line asks, is there a formula for finding the number of nonisomorphic simple graphs there are with n nodes, outside of trial, error, and enumeration over max degrees of vertices?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [OEIS A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088). Two asymptotic formulas are given, the first of which is

$$a(n)=\frac{2^{\binom{n}2}}{n!}\left(1+\frac{n^2-n}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{8n!(3n-7)(3n-9)}{2^{2n}(n-4)!}\right)+O\left(\frac{n^5}{2^{5n/2}}\right)\;,$$

but there does not appear to be a nice closed form.

Comment: Thanks for the response... so for small values of n, drawing them seems to be the path of least resistance.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: You’re welcome. Or simply using the OEIS data for $n\le 19$. (And since that’s already $24637809253125004524383007491432768$, for any bigger $n$ an approximation might be adequate anyhow.)

Comment: Actually the table goes up to $n=75$ in the [b-file](http://oeis.org/A000088/b000088.txt).  These numbers must have been found by a non-constructive method of counting.  I'm guessing [Polya's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem); an implementation is discussed [here](http://www.roard.com/docs/cookbook/cbsu5.html).