# Number of distinct connected digraphs with 4 vertices and 6 edges

Tags: graph-theory

I have been looking at graphs representing how people or things can move between states (vertices).  Each directional move from one vertex directly to another is an edge, and each vertex must be reachable from every other vertex.

My question is "How many distinct graphs are there with 4 vertices and 6 edges?"  By "distinct, I mean that no graph can be turned into another by flipping, rotating, or re-labeling the vertices.

I would also appreciate pointers to the more general question of the number of distinct graphs that arise with V vertices and 2(V-1) edges.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a digraph? Do you allow loops and multiple edges, e.g. vertices a, b, c, d and edges aa, ab, bc, cd, da, da? Just out of curiosity, what is the significance of 2(V-1) in your question? What is special about graphs with V vertices and 2(V-1) edges?

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354062/how-many-nonisomorphic-directed-simple-graphs-are-there-with-n-vertices-when) which doesn't answer, but gives a method of approach.  There remains the question of whether or not you consider bi-directional edges to be one edge or two.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.  Unfortunately, your mathematics is beyond me.  The graph I have in mind does not have loops from a vertex back to itself.  The edge from vertex 1 to vertex 2 is NOT the same as the edge from vertex 2 to vertex 1. Both edges are possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.  Unfortunately, your mathematics is beyond me.  The graph I have in mind does not have loops from a vertex back to itself; the edge from vertex 1 to vertex 2 is NOT the same as the edge from vertex 2 to vertex 1; both are possible.   Could you please provide a simplified answer as to the number of distinct graphs with 4 vertices and 6 edges, and how those different graphs can be identified.  I know that for 2 vertices, there is one possible graph, and for 3 vertices there are 3.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In the particular case of 4 vertices and 6 edges, we can generate them exhaustively.  I use some [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code below.

Step 1: generate all labelled digraphs:

```
nrVert:=4;;
nrEdges:=2*(nrVert-1);;

LabelledDigraphs:=[];

DigraphBacktracking:=function(v,edgeSet)
  local deg,outNeighborSet,newedgeSet;

  for deg in [0..Minimum(nrEdges-Size(edgeSet),nrVert-1)] do
    for outNeighborSet in Combinations([1..nrVert],deg) do

      # loops are not allowed
      if(v in outNeighborSet) then continue; fi;

      # add new directed edges
      newedgeSet:=Concatenation(edgeSet,List(outNeighborSet,u->[v,u]));

      if(v<nrVert) then
        DigraphBacktracking(v+1,newedgeSet);
      else
        if(Size(newedgeSet)=nrEdges) then
          LabelledDigraphs:=Concatenation(LabelledDigraphs,[newedgeSet]);
        fi;
      fi;

    od;
  od;
end;;

# start backtracking
DigraphBacktracking(1,[]);
```

Then we filter out isomorphic representatives, which we can do by brute force (i.e., compute the entire isomorphism class) since the parameters are small:

```
# brute-force computes the isomorphism class; finds minimum
IsomorphismClassRepresentative:=function(edgeSet)
  local alpha,permutededgeSet,IsomorphismClass;

  IsomorphismClass:=[];
  for alpha in SymmetricGroup(nrVert) do
    permutededgeSet:=SortedList(List(edgeSet,e->[e[1]^alpha,e[2]^alpha]));
    IsomorphismClass:=Concatenation(IsomorphismClass,[permutededgeSet]);
  od;

  return Minimum(IsomorphismClass);
end;;

UnlabelledDigraphs:=Set(LabelledDigraphs,edgeSet->IsomorphismClassRepresentative(edgeSet));
```

Then I wrote a script to print them, giving the 48 digraphs drawn below:

[image]

For 4-vertex 4-edge digraphs, we get these four:

[image]

This agrees with Marko Riedel's answer in these cases.

Comment: Highly professional work. Very impressive. (+1) Do you mean three-vertex four-edge digraphs?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an  answer to help get started, namely  the count of connected
non-isomorphic graphs.  With $\mathcal{G}$  the combinatorial class of
non-isomorphic  graphs and  $\mathcal{C}$ of  connected non-isomorphic
graphs we have a multiset relationship, namely

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\mathcal{G} 
= \textsc{MSET}(\mathcal{C}).$$

The astute  reader will note that  this holds for digraphs  and graphs
with self-loops as well (with a different $\mathcal{G}$).  Translating
to generating  functions the  combinatorial class equation  yields (we
use $z$ for the number of vertices and $u$ for the number of edges)

$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{C(z^l, u^l)}{l}\right).$$

Differentiatiation will produce

$$G'(z, u) = G(z, u) \sum_{l\ge 1} C'(z^l, u^l) z^{l-1}.$$

Extracting coefficients on $[z^n]$ we obtain

$$(n+1) G_{n+1} = \sum_{q=0}^n G_{n-q} 
[z^q] \sum_{l\ge 1} C'(z^l, u^l) z^{l-1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n G_{n-q} 
\sum_{l=1}^{q+1} [z^{q-(l-1)}] C'(z^l, u^l)
\\ = \sum_{l=1}^{n+1}
\sum_{q=l-1}^n  G_{n-q}  [z^{q-(l-1)}] C'(z^l, u^l)
= \sum_{l=1}^{n+1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-(l-1)}  G_{n-q-(l-1)}  [z^{q}] C'(z^l, u^l).$$

Here we must have $q = pl$ and we get

$$\sum_{l=1}^{n+1}
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/l \rfloor -1}  
G_{n+1-(p+1)l}  [z^{pl}] C'(z^l, u^l)
\\ = \sum_{l=1}^{n+1}
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/l \rfloor -1}  
G_{n+1-(p+1)l}  [z^{p}] C'(z, u^l)
\\ = \sum_{l=1}^{n+1}
\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/l \rfloor -1}  
G_{n+1-(p+1)l} (p+1) C_{p+1}(u^l)
= \sum_{l=1}^{n+1}
\sum_{p=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/l \rfloor}  
G_{n+1-pl} p C_p(u^l)
\\ = \sum_{pl\le n+1} G_{n+1-pl} p C_p(u^l).$$

Introducing $k=pl$ we finally obtain

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  G_{n+1-k} \sum_{p|k} p C_p(u^{k/p})
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^{n}  G_{n+1-k} \sum_{p|k} p C_p(u^{k/p})
+ \sum_{p|n+1 \wedge p\lt n+1} p C_p(u^{(n+1)/p})  
+ (n+1) C_{n+1}(u).$$

We thus have the recurrence

$$C_{n+1}(u) = G_{n+1}
\\ - \frac{1}{n+1} 
\sum_{k=1}^{n}  G_{n+1-k} \sum_{p|k} p C_p(u^{k/p})
- \frac{1}{n+1}  
\sum_{p|n+1 \wedge p\lt n+1} p C_p(u^{(n+1)/p})$$

or alternatively for $n\ge 2$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
C_n(u) = G_{n}
- \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  G_{n-k} \sum_{p|k} p C_p(u^{k/p})
- \frac{1}{n}  \sum_{p|n \wedge p\lt n} p C_p(u^{n/p}).}$$

Note however  that the coefficients  $G_n$ for all graphs  rather than
connected only are  not difficult to compute, for  the details consult
the                           following                           [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088991/),    where   we
encounter  the following  classification  according to  the number  of
edges.

For $n=4,$ we get
$$G_4 = {u}^{6}+{u}^{5}+2\,{u}^{4}+3\,{u}^{3}+2\,{u}^{2}+u+1$$

and for $n=5,$

$$G_5 = {u}^{10}+{u}^{9}+2\,{u}^{8}+4\,{u}^{7}+6\,{u}^{6}+6\,{u}^{5}
\\+6\,{u}^{4}+4\,{u}^{3}+2\,{u}^{2}+u+1$$

and for $n=6,$ the last one,

$$G_6 = {u}^{15}+{u}^{14}+2\,{u}^{13}+5\,{u}^{12}+9\,{u}^{11}
\\+15\,{u}^{10}+21\,{u}^{9}+24\,{u}^{8}+24\,{u}^{7}+21\,{u}^{6}
\\+15\,{u}^{5}+9\,{u}^{4}+5\,{u}^{3}+2\,{u}^{2}+u+1.$$

Setting $u=1$ we obtain the total count of non-isomorphic graphs which
starts with

$$1, 2, 4, 11, 34, 156, 1044, 12346, 274668, 12005168,\ldots$$

which  point us to  [OEIS A000088](https://oeis.org/A000088)  where we
find that we have the right values.

Using these values together with the recurrence that was derived above
yields   the  generating   functions   for  connected   non-isomorphic
graphs. (We must  pay attention to get the base  cases right, they are
$1$ and $1$ for $G_0$ and $G_1$  and $0$ and $1$ for $C_0$ and $C_1.$)
We thus have

$$C_4 = {u}^{6}+{u}^{5}+2\,{u}^{4}+2\,{u}^{3}$$

and furthermore

$$C_5 = {u}^{10}+{u}^{9}+2\,{u}^{8}+4\,{u}^{7}
\\+5\,{u}^{6}+5\,{u}^{5}+3\,{u}^{4}$$

and finally

$$C_6 = {u}^{15}+{u}^{14}+2\,{u}^{13}+5\,{u}^{12}
\\+9\,{u}^{11}+14\,{u}^{10}+20\,{u}^{9}+22\,{u}^{8}+19\,{u}^{7}
\\+13\,{u}^{6}+6\,{u}^{5}.$$

Observe that the  smallest degree term ($n-1$ edges)  counts trees and
indeed we obtain

$$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 23, 47, 106, 235, 551, 1301, 3159, 7741, 
\\ 19320, 48629, 123867, 317955, 823065,\ldots$$

which  point  us  to  [OEIS  A000055](https://oeis.org/A000055).   (We
compute these  with the Maple code  that will be presented  at the end
and it works quite nicely where resource allocation is concerned.)

Setting $u=1$ in the $C_n$ terms yields the sequence

$$1, 1, 2, 6, 21, 112, 853, 11117, 261080, 11716571, 1006700565, 
\\ 164059830476, 50335907869219, 29003487462848061, 
\\ 31397381142761241960, 63969560113225176176277,\ldots $$

which  is   [OEIS  A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349)  and  presumably
motivated this entire calculation.

To conclude we answer the question of the OP who asks about the number
of non-isomorphic  graphs with  $2n-2$ edges. We  get for  the general
case the sequence

$$1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 15, 131, 1646, 27987, 596191, 15108047, 
\\ 440393606, 14441470390,\ldots$$

which does not  yet have an OEIS entry. We get  for the connected case
the sequence

$$1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 14, 126, 1579, 26631, 561106, 14013042, 401665379, 
\\ 12932769342, 461011580013, 18001615191104, 
\\ 763685360909770, 34964179546197292,\ldots$$

which is not yet in the OEIS either.

The Maple code for this computation follows.  We include everything
here  even  though  there  is  some  overlap with  the  link  that  we
referenced, so that the reader does  not have to look for and join the
different constituents.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_edg :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local all, term, termvars, res, l1, l2, inst1, u, v,
    uidx, vidx;

    if n=0 or n=1 then return 1; fi;

    all := 0:
    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            l1 := op(1, u);

            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                l2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]
                ^((l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            if type(l1, odd) then
                # a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-1)))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-2)))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;

        all := all + lcoeff(term)*res;
    od;

    all;
end;


pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res, k;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

G :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    if n=0 then return 1 fi;
    expand(pet_varinto_cind(1+u, pet_cycleind_edg(n)));
end;

C :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, k, p;
    if n=0 then return 0 fi;
    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    res := G(n)
    - 1/n*add(G(n-k)
              *add(p*subs(u=u^(k/p), C(p)),
                   p in divisors(k)), k=1..n-1)
    - 1/n*add(p*subs(u=u^(n/p), C(p)),
              p in divisors(n) minus {n});

    expand(res);
end;

TRIANG_G :=
proc(m)
    local n, k;
    seq(seq(coeff(G(n), u, k), k=0..n*(n-1)/2),
        n=1..m);
end;

TRIANG_C :=
proc(m)
    local n, k;
    seq(seq(coeff(C(n), u, k), k=n-1..n*(n-1)/2),
        n=1..m);
end;
```

**Addendum  I, Mar  15  2017.** Here  are  the data  for  the case  of
digraphs  and weakly connected  digraphs. The  cycle index  is simpler
actually than in the case of ordinary graphs because the edges are now
ordered  pairs rather than  sets. We  must be  careful however  not to
include self  loops. With these  observations we obtain for  $n=3$ the
corresponding

$$G_3 = {u}^{6}+{u}^{5}+4\,{u}^{4}+4\,{u}^{3}+4\,{u}^{2}+u+1$$

and for $n=4$

$$G_4 = 
{u}^{12}+{u}^{11}+5\,{u}^{10}+13\,{u}^{9}+27\,{u}^{8}+38\,{u}^{7}
\\+48\,{u}^{6}+38\,{u}^{5}+27\,{u}^{4}+13\,{u}^{3}+5\,{u}^{2}+u+1$$

and finally

$$G_5 =
{u}^{20}+{u}^{19}+5\,{u}^{18}+16\,{u}^{17}+61\,{u}^{16}
\\+154\,{u}^{15}+379\,{u}^{14}+707\,{u}^{13}+1155\,{u}^{12}
\\+1490\,{u}^{11}+1670\,{u}^{10}+1490\,{u}^{9}+1155\,{u}^{8}
\\+707\,{u}^{7}+379\,{u}^{6}+154\,{u}^{5}+61\,{u}^{4}
\\+16\,{u}^{3}+5\,{u}^{2}+u+1$$

The sequence here is

$$1, 3, 16, 218, 9608, 1540944, 882033440, 1793359192848, 
\\ 13027956824399552, 341260431952972580352,\ldots$$

which  points  us  to [OEIS  A000273](https://oeis.org/A000273)  where
these values are  confirmed. We get for weakly  connected digraphs the
corresponding

$$C_3 = {u}^{6}+{u}^{5}+4\,{u}^{4}+4\,{u}^{3}+3\,{u}^{2}$$

and

$$C_4 = 
{u}^{12}+{u}^{11}+5\,{u}^{10}+13\,{u}^{9}+27\,{u}^{8}
\\+38\,{u}^{7}+47\,{u}^{6}+37\,{u}^{5}+22\,{u}^{4}+8\,{u}^{3}$$

and finally

$$C_5 =
{u}^{20}+{u}^{19}+5\,{u}^{18}+16\,{u}^{17}+61\,{u}^{16}+154\,{u}^{15}
\\+379\,{u}^{14}+707\,{u}^{13}+1154\,{u}^{12}+1489\,{u}^{11}
\\+1665\,{u}^{10}+1477\,{u}^{9}+1127\,{u}^{8}+667\,{u}^{7}
\\+326\,{u}^{6}+108\,{u}^{5}+27\,{u}^{4}$$

The lowest  entries in  these count directed  trees and we  obtain the
sequence

$$1, 1, 3, 8, 27, 91, 350, 1376, 5743, 24635, 108968, 492180, 
\\ 2266502, 10598452, 50235931,\ldots $$

which is [OEIS A000238](http://oeis.org/A000238). Setting $u=1$ in the
$C_n$ sequence we obtain

$$1, 2, 13, 199, 9364, 1530843, 880471142, 1792473955306,
\\ 13026161682466252, 341247400399400765678,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS  A003085](https://oeis.org/A003085). The new Maple code
goes as follows (making use of the material included above).

```
pet_cycleind_edg_dg :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local all, term, termvars, res, l1, l2, inst1, u, v,
    uidx, vidx;

    if n=0 or n=1 then return 1; fi;

    all := 0:
    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            l1 := op(1, u);

            # edges on different cycles of different sizes
            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                l2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]
                ^(2*(l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
            
            # edges on different cycles of the same size
            # edges on identical cycles of some size
            inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/l1)
            # a[l1]^(inst1*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(inst1*(inst1-1)*l1 +
                   (l1-1)*inst1);
        od;

        all := all + lcoeff(term)*res;
    od;

    all;
end;

GDG :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    if n=0 then return 1 fi;
    expand(pet_varinto_cind(1+u, pet_cycleind_edg_dg(n)));
end;

CDG :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, k, p;
    if n=0 then return 0 fi;
    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    res := GDG(n)
    - 1/n*add(GDG(n-k)
              *add(p*subs(u=u^(k/p), CDG(p)),
                   p in divisors(k)), k=1..n-1)
    - 1/n*add(p*subs(u=u^(n/p), CDG(p)),
              p in divisors(n) minus {n});

    expand(res);
end;

TRIANG_GDG :=
proc(m)
    local n, k;
    seq(seq(coeff(GDG(n), u, k), k=0..n*(n-1)),
        n=1..m);
end;

TRIANG_CDG :=
proc(m)
    local n, k;
    seq(seq(coeff(CDG(n), u, k), k=n-1..n*(n-1)),
        n=1..m);
end;
```

The  OP  asked for  $2n-2$  edges.  We  get without  restrictions  the
sequence

$$1, 1, 4, 48, 1155, 43863, 2271936, 148148461, 
\\11647251760, 1072087150138,\ldots$$

and in the connected case

$$1, 1, 4, 47, 1127, 42148, 2144407, 137134237, 
\\10565885538, 952629680882,\ldots$$

**Addendum II, Mar 16 2017.** For the sake of completeness let us also
solve the  case of  ordinary graphs with  loops permitted.   The cycle
index here is  augmented term by term by  multiplying the contribution
from  ordinary  graphs,  which   is  the  symmetric  group  of  vertex
permutations acting on the edges, by the action factorized into cycles
of  that  same  vertex  permutation  on the  $n$  possible  self-loops
attached  to the  vertices.   The  code for  this  is obtained  almost
instantly from the code for the case of ordinary graphs but we do have
to get the base cases right which now demand $G_1 = C_1 = 1 + u.$ This
yields for $G_3$

$$G_3 = {u}^{6}+2\,{u}^{5}+4\,{u}^{4}+6\,{u}^{3}+4\,{u}^{2}+2\,u+1$$

and for $G_4$

$$G_4 = {u}^{10}+2\,{u}^{9}+5\,{u}^{8}+11\,{u}^{7}+17\,{u}^{6}
\\+18\,{u}^{5}+17\,{u}^{4}+11\,{u}^{3}+5\,{u}^{2}+2\,u+1$$

and finally for $G_5$

$$G_5 = {u}^{15}+2\,{u}^{14}+5\,{u}^{13}+13\,{u}^{12}
\\+29\,{u}^{11}+52\,{u}^{10}+76\,{u}^{9}+94\,{u}^{8}
\\+94\,{u}^{7}+76\,{u}^{6}+52\,{u}^{5}+29\,{u}^{4}
\\+13\,{u}^{3}+5\,{u}^{2}+2\,u+1.$$

The sequence now becomes

$$2, 6, 20, 90, 544, 5096, 79264, 2208612, 113743760, 10926227136,
\\ 1956363435360, 652335084592096, 405402273420996800, \ldots $$

which is  [OEIS A000666](https://oeis.org/A000666) and  which looks to
be the  right entry.  We obtain for  connected graphs  with self-loops
that

$$C_3 = {u}^{6}+2\,{u}^{5}+3\,{u}^{4}+3\,{u}^{3}+{u}^{2}$$

and that

$$C_4 = {u}^{10}+2\,{u}^{9}+5\,{u}^{8}+10\,{u}^{7}+13\,{u}^{6}
\\+11\,{u}^{5}+6\,{u}^{4}+2\,{u}^{3}$$

and finally

$$C_5 = {u}^{15}+2\,{u}^{14}+5\,{u}^{13}+13\,{u}^{12}
\\+28\,{u}^{11}+49\,{u}^{10}+68\,{u}^{9}+75\,{u}^{8}+61\,{u}^{7}
\\+35\,{u}^{6}+14\,{u}^{5}+3\,{u}^{4}.$$

Observe that the lowest degree term once more counts trees and we get

$$ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 23, 47, 106, 235, 551, 1301, 3159, \ldots$$

as before. The sequence corresponding to the $C_n$ is

$$2, 3, 10, 50, 354, 3883, 67994, 2038236, 109141344, 10693855251, 
\\ 1934271527050, 648399961915988, 404093642681273382,\ldots$$

which is [OEIS A054921](https://oeis.org/A054921), and looks correct.
The modified Maple code now runs as follows.

```
pet_cycleind_edg_sl :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local all, term, termvars, res, l1, l2, inst1, u, v,
    uidx, vidx;

    if n=0 or n=1 then return 1; fi;

    all := 0:
    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            l1 := op(1, u);

            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                l2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]
                ^((l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            if type(l1, odd) then
                # a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-1)))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-2)))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;

        all := all + term*res;
    od;

    all;
end;

GSL :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    if n=0 then return 1 fi;
    if n=1 then return 1+u fi;
    expand(pet_varinto_cind(1+u, pet_cycleind_edg_sl(n)));
end;

CSL :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local res, k, p;
    if n=0 then return 0 fi;
    if n=1 then return 1+u fi;

    res := GSL(n)
    - 1/n*add(GSL(n-k)
              *add(p*subs(u=u^(k/p), CSL(p)),
                   p in divisors(k)), k=1..n-1)
    - 1/n*add(p*subs(u=u^(n/p), CSL(p)),
              p in divisors(n) minus {n});

    expand(res);
end;

TRIANG_GSL :=
proc(m)
    local n, k;
    seq(seq(coeff(GSL(n), u, k), k=0..n*(n+1)/2),
        n=1..m);
end;

TRIANG_CSL :=
proc(m)
    local n, k;
    seq(seq(coeff(CSL(n), u, k), k=n-1..n*(n+1)/2),
        n=1..m);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The  following Maple  code  uses  Maple and  PostScript  to produce  a
diagram of  the $29$  unique graphs with  self-loops on  five vertices
having four edges. The image is shown below.

```
with(combinat);

PLOTG5E4L :=
proc()
local edges, choice, perm, orbits, orbit, uniqorbs,
    sl, loc, vertloc, looploc, fd, vert, line,
    prolog, rot, current, inst, edg;

    edges :=
    {seq(seq({p, q}, q=p+1..5), p=1..5),
     seq({p}, p=1..5)};

    orbits := table();

    for choice in choose(edges, 4) do
        orbit := [];

        for perm in permute(5) do
            sl := [seq(p=perm[p], p=1..5)];
            orbit :=
            [op(orbit), subs(sl, choice)];
        od;

        orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
    od;

    vertloc := []; looploc := [];
    for rot from 0 to 4 do
        loc := exp(rot*2*Pi*I/5);

        vertloc :=
        [op(vertloc), [Re(loc), Im(loc)]];

        looploc :=
        [op(looploc), [Re(loc)*3/2, Im(loc)*3/2]];
    od;

    uniqorbs := [indices(orbits, 'nolist')];

    current := 0;
    fd := fopen(`noniso-g5e4l.ps`, WRITE);

    prolog :=
    ["%!PS-Adobe-1.0",
     "%%Creator: Marko Riedel",
     "%%Title: graph orbits",
     sprintf("%%%%BoundingBox: 0 0 %d %d",
             (1+4*4)*20,
             (1+4*ceil(nops(uniqorbs)/4))*20),
     "%%Pages: 1",
     "%%EndComments"];

    for line in prolog do
        fprintf(fd, "%s\n", line);
    od;

    fprintf(fd, "%%Page 1 1\n\n");

    fprintf(fd, "0.05 setlinewidth\n");
    fprintf(fd, "20 20 scale\n");

    for inst in uniqorbs do
        fprintf(fd, "gsave\n");
        fprintf(fd, "%f %f translate\n",
                2+4*irem(current, 4),
                2+4*iquo(current, 4));

        for edg in inst do
            if nops(edg) = 2 then
                fprintf(fd, "%f %f moveto\n",
                        vertloc[op(1, edg)][1],
                        vertloc[op(1, edg)][2]);
                fprintf(fd, "%f %f lineto\n",
                        vertloc[op(2, edg)][1],
                        vertloc[op(2, edg)][2]);
            else
                fprintf(fd, "%f %f moveto\n",
                        looploc[op(1, edg)][1]+0.4,
                        looploc[op(1, edg)][2]);
                fprintf(fd, "%f %f 0.4 0 360 arc\n",
                        looploc[op(1, edg)][1],
                        looploc[op(1, edg)][2]);
            fi;
        od;

        fprintf(fd, "stroke\n");

        for vert to 5 do
            fprintf(fd, "0 1 0 setrgbcolor\n");
            fprintf(fd, "%f %f 0.4 0 360 arc\n",
                    vertloc[vert][1], vertloc[vert][2]);
            fprintf(fd, "fill\n");


            fprintf(fd, "0 0 0 setrgbcolor\n");
            fprintf(fd, "%f %f 0.4 0 360 arc\n",
                    vertloc[vert][1], vertloc[vert][2]);
            fprintf(fd, "stroke\n");
        od;

        fprintf(fd, "grestore\n");
        current := current + 1;
    od;


    fprintf(fd, "showpage\n");
    fclose(fd);

    true;
end;
```

[image: graphs with loops on five vertices with four edges under isomorphism]