# Are there exactly 79 seven edges connected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve some basic graph theory problem and I want to know how many seven edges connected graphs are there. I think the exact number is 79 but I am not sure.
For example for the case of six edges I have obtained 30 connected graphs.
Thank you for your helps.

Comment: This question was examined by using the Polya Enumeration Theorem at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187019/). The output from the Maple code that was posted there indeed yields $79.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems correct. The numbers are 4, 19, 33, and 23 graphs on 5, 6, 7, and 8 vertices respectively.

---

Not too hard to verify using SageMath via the following code:

```
graph_list=[]
# number of vertices is at least 5 and at most 8.
for n in range(5,9):
    for g in graphs(n):
        if g.is_connected() and g.num_edges()==7:
            graph_list.append(g)
print len(graph_list)
# For some pictures! :-)
graphs_list.show_graphs(graph_list)
```

This is a brute force approach and takes a bit more than a minute to run at the [sagecell server](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjs0KwyAQhO-C77DHFUpupbTgk5QiEjcbIV1FDX39RtKfzHG-GWa4-Dy7JdZm7w-ttJpSAYEoULww4fl0NTetYFMn3An3TkX5gq44AQ-xujGJ0NgooAEvYTNlfToKTBWNtZdDpYt_84PPmSQgG61yidJgIcE_3-x9d0_XOb3c58gh9AbFTkCJ&lang=sage).

Answer (score 1):

This agrees with the numbers tabulated [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphcounts.txt) (which is linked to from [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html))

It lists the number of connected graphs ( and all graphs ) first by numbers of vertices and then by number of edges for a given number of vertices.

[This](http://atlas.gregas.eu/sources) is another useful link to resources.

Comment: That table indicates there are $30$ connected graphs with $6$ edges, so the OP must have overlooked one.  See also http://oeis.org/A002905

Comment: Yes it appears so. OEIS, a very useful link.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: 30 sounds about right, via nauty's geng. Did OP miss $K_4$? :P