# What is the number of connected graphs with $n$ vertices of max. degree up to $P$? Leaving $F(x) = x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 6x^4 + 21x^5 + ...$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

It is known that F(x) is the generating function of the counting sequence of connected simple graphs with N vertices is given by:

$F(x) = x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 6x^4 + 21x^5 + 112x^6 + ...$

where the total number of connected graphs of $n$ vertices is obtained by the coefficient corresponding to $x^n$.

**The question here is**: How to find the series (or formula) to get the counting of connected simple graphs with $n$ vertices of maximum degree up to $P$? (generalizing with at least $1$ vertice with maximum degree equal to $P$)

For example, for $n = 5$ with $P=3$, we have $8$ connected graphs with at least $1$ vertice with maximum degree equal to $3$, and for $n = 5$ with $P=4$, we have $11$ connected graphs with at least $1$ vertice with maximum degree equal to $4$, as shown the degree distribution in the illustration below:
[image]

Follows a table of the count of the first groups of graphs according to the number of vertices and the maximum degree:
[image]
My question in brief is to determine the number of connected graphs with max. degree $P$ for a given number of Nodes $n$.

OBS: Do not get confused! the question does not include Disconnected Graphs, Digraphs, Labeled Graphs, number of cubic or quartic graphs!

Anyone know a solution to this intriguing problem? help me!

**Note:**

F(x) is the generating function of the counting sequence of connected structures, then the corresponding generating function G(x) of the counting sequence of all structures is given by:

$$G(x) = exp \sum_{k>=1} F(x^k)/k = \sum_{i=0} b_i x^k$$

Applying a variant of the Mobius inversion to equation above, it is possible to
express F(x) in terms of G(x):

$$F(x) = exp \sum_{k>=1} [\mu(x)/k]log G(x^k) = \sum_{i=0} a_i x^k$$

Where $\mu$ stands for the Mobius function.

Let $a_n$ be the number of connected graphs on $n$ vertices and $b_n$ the number of all graphs on $n$ vertices. Then:

$F(x) = x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 6x^4 + 21x^5 + 112x^6 + 853x^7 + ...$

and

$G(x) = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 4x^3 + 11x^4 + 34x^5 + 156x^6 + ...$

I saw this on "Counting Disconnected Structures: Chemical Trees, Fullerenes, I-graphs" on the link: https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/4232  but I did not understand how I can use it in favor of my problem.

**An observation:**

If $T(n)$ represents the total of connected graphs of $n$ nodes and $D_p(n)$ represents the total of connected sub-graphs group with max. degree $P$, and knowing that $P_{max} = (n-1)$, we can write:
$$ T(n) = D_1(n) + D_2(n) + D_3(n) + ... + D_{n-1}(n)$$

For $n>2$, we know that $D_1(n) = 0$ and $D_2(n) = 2$, so we have to:
$$T(n) = 2 + D_3(n) + ... + D_{n-1}(n)$$

Note also that $D_{n-1}$ is obtained by the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ of $G(x)$.

But how to calculate $D_p(n)$?

OBS: Another way to attack the problem I posted on the link [About counting the number of graphs by the maximum Degree $D$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574213/about-counting-the-number-of-graphs-by-the-maximum-degree-d)

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A001349](http://oeis.org/A001349) "Number of connected graphs with n nodes" and read some of the entries, computer code, and references.

Comment: The OGF $F(x)$ was computed at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187019/) along with several others.

Comment: Clearly if we have the generic case we can compute the connected case. NAUTY says for the generic case we have classified by maximum degree for $n=8$ nodes: $$1,  4,  41,  378,  2166,  4869,  3843,  1044$$ which points to [OEIS A263293](https://oeis.org/A263293). On the other hand restricting to the connected case NAUTY produces for $n=8$ maximum degree $$0,  0,  2,  192,  1735,  4457,  3687,  1044$$ which is not in the OEIS. Harary and Palmer list it as an open problem.

Comment: Thank you @Marko Riedel, i have seen many sequences in the OEIS but none fits this problem. I also need to start from an equation or development to prove the solution. Maybe an equation where I can define parameters to arrive at these sub-graphs.