# How to predict all non-isomorphic connected simple graphs are there with $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

> $(1)\:$How many non-isomorphic connected simple graphs are there with $n$ vertices when n is,
>   $\qquad(a)\:4\qquad(b)\:5$
>   
> $(2)\:$Draw all non-isomorphic, cycle free, connected graphs having six vertices.

For $(1)$ when $n=4$, it's only $6$ case I got. But when it is $5$, I was unable to find out $21$ case. Actually I found $15$ case and here is my question arrive,

> Is there any prediction without drawing all of those case$?$ If not then how could someone ensure his/her answer in Exam $(\text{For big enough n})?$

For $(2)$ I have the same situation.
I was thinking there should be other way to predict the answer of this kind question. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advances.

Comment: The following [MSE link on non-isomorphic connected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187019/) might prove useful.

Comment: Seems like induction on the maximum degree of a vertex ought to go a long way in the cycle-free case.  If $n=4$, I can only find two connected cycle-free graphs.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel It seems to understand your answer$(\text{Linked})$ I need many stuff to study. But at that time it will be best if I have a generating function/recurrence relation to get my desire answer. Can you provide any$?$ And thanks for your response I will definitely read your answer$(\text{Linked})$ after exam.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Any OEIS sequence which can tell for $n=1,\cdots,10?$

Comment: [oeis](https://oeis.org/A001349) but there does not seem to be any generating function of formula.

Comment: For $(2)$ It should be all possible trees with $6$ nodes @NajmunNahar

Answer (score 1):

I tried for $(2)$ and got $6$ case$(\text{Sorry for my poor drawing})$, 
[image]

I think the main hack will be to find all possible tree.