# How many of different connected graphs with n vertices? Excluding of isomorphic graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, oeis

Given $n$ vertices, the question is to answer how many different connected graphs exist?

For example, $f(1)=1,f(2)=1,f(3)=2,f(4)=6 \cdots$.

Here I exclude the isomorphic graphs.

I know there is a sequence http://oeis.org/A001349

But can anyone try to explain how to calculate the sequence?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed formula?

Comment: The link to the oeis entry contains several references that should answer your question.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker Yes, is there a closed formula?

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088) "Number of onnected graphs with n nodes" has formulas and computer code. The sequences A000088 and A001349 are connected by the Euler transform.

Comment: This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187019/) may prove useful.