# Symbolic method for unlabelled connected graphs with $n$ nodes

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

I am trying to find an ordinary generating function using Flajolet's symbolic method to count unlabelled connected graphs with $n$ nodes ([OEIS A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349)).

I can't see which constructions can correspond ($\text{Seq}(\mathcal{Z}), \text{Set}(\mathcal{Z}),$etc) or some functional equation.

I have not been able to find help in any bibliography, I understand that the generating function must be seen in the form $1+x+x^2+2x^3+6x^4+...$

I am interested in finding a general formula for the ordinary generating function to obtain these coefficients.  Does anyone have a bibliography of which constructions of the symbolic method can help me?  or in this case the symbolic method does not apply?

Comment: The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187019/) has a detailed computation of these graphs by  the number of edges.