# Lower Bound on the Number of Graph Isomorphism Classes

Tags: graph-theory

Are there any non-trivial lower bounds on the number of isomorphism classes for a graph with $N$ vertices?

For example there are at least $N(N-1)/2$ isomorphism classes (counting one for the number of possible edges in our graph) but as $N$ increases, there will clearly be a lot more.

Comment: Here's a magic answer : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353053/is-there-a-formula-for-finding-the-number-of-nonisomorphic-simple-graphs-that-ha

Comment: Why's it magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to say what you mean by non-trivial. What do you want to use the bound for? But, gripes aside, $2^{\binom{n}2}/n!$ is a lower bound and asymptotically tight.

Comment: I meant $N(N-1)/2$ as the trivial lower bound. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: The number of graphs in the isomorphism class of $G$ is $n!/|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$, so it's at most $n!$. So the number of isomorphism classes is at least $2^n/n!$. I do not think a reference is necessary.

Comment: $2^{{n \choose 2}}/n!$. Yes that is enough.