# Counting the ways agents can like or dislike one another

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a multiagent system where each agent may either like or dislike another agent.  For two agents, there are three distinct cases: the agents (i) mutually like each other; (ii) mutually dislike each other; or (iii) the first likes the second but the second does not like the first.  (There is a symmetric second case for (iii).)

My question, which I have been unable to work out the answer to, is: what is the number of distinct cases for $n$ agents?  Distinct here means that a case cannot be transformed into another by relabeling the agents.  The number of cases (not necessarily distinct) seems to be $n \times 2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking for the number of directed graphs with $10$ nodes.
The idea is that each node is an agent and an edge from node $a$ to $b$ means $a$ likes $b$.

Much like in the case for [simple graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353053/is-there-a-formula-for-finding-the-number-of-nonisomorphic-simple-graphs-that-ha), I don't think there's a neat closed formula for this, although asymptotic estimates are known.
That said, there's an entry in the OEIS for this: [Sloane's $A000273$](http://oeis.org/A000273).
According to it, the answer is

$$341260431952972580352$$

Comment: I think the answer is larger than this (depending on you definition of a directed graph). In the quesiton formulation, an edge may be bidirectional.

Comment: Directed graphs may have bidirectional edges. Oriented graphs may not.

Comment: @Arthur Here is OEIS's entry for oriented graphs: [link](http://oeis.org/A001174).

Comment: I did not know that, but it seems you are right. Are loops allowed in Sloane's directed graphs?

Comment: I meant loops of length 1. Those shouldn't be counted for this problem, and it seems both conventions are used for digraphs.

Comment: I don't see why not. Oriented graphs may also contain loops, provided they are not of length two (because that would simply be a disguised bidirectional edge).

Comment: Checking small values of $n$, like $n=2$ or $3$, seems to indicate that loops of length one are not allowed on digraphs (nor on oriented graphs for that matter).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: I don't think it's quite that.  If you want to formulate my problem in terms of graphs, it is to count all distinct graphs of $n$ nodes where there is always an edge between any two nodes, but edges may be unidirectional in either direction, or bidirectional, or have no direction at all.

Comment: I don't think I get what you propose. How exactly does my translation to graphs fail to model the problem, and how does your translation correct that?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, first of all the problem is with $n$ nodes, not 10 in particular (i.e., to find a combinatorial expression, not a particular value in a specific case), and secondly you are looking only at directed edges, whilst edges may be undirected as well.

Comment: What does an undirected edge mean?